# Parse Cloud Code Nested Querys

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

**tl:dr:**
`Edited my post and posted an answer resolving the issue with parallel promises.`

I don't know if I understand Javascript promises correctly.

First of all: **My Parse.Job works.** And it does what it should do.

Second: Yes, I need to compare every single User to all of the other users. You might, of course, suggest some better method to do that but my main issue is the "did not call error/success" problem with the following script.

The error:

`E2016-01-05T18:37:10.740Z]v255 Ran job checkSth with:
  Input: {}
  Result: success/error was not called`

The Script:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("checkSth", function(request, response) { // begin Cloud.Job("checkSth")

  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var users = []

  userQuery.each(function(user){ // [0] userQuery.each
    users.push(user)
    console.log(users)
    var currentUser = user;

    userQuery.each(function(user){ // [1] userQuery.each
      if (user == currentUser){
        console.log("$$$$$$$ SAME USER $$$$$$$")
      } else {
        if (currentUser.get("memberIDs").indexOf(user.get("memberId")) > -1 ){
          console.log("Found (different) member user!")
        }
      }

    }).then(function(){
      console.log("User: " + user)
    }, function(error){
      response.error("Error")
    }) // [1] userQuery.each    
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("Users: " + users)
    response.success("Success")
  }, function(error){
    response.error("Error")
  }) // [0] userQuery.each

}) // end Cloud.Job("checkSth")
```

Maybe anyone of you can help me.

**EDIT: Solved with promises!**

```
Parse.Cloud.job("doSth", function(request, status) { // begin Cloud.Job("doSth")
  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var users = []
  var promises = []
  promises.push( // Start Promise [0]
userQuery.each(function(user){ // userQuery.each [0]

  var currentUser = user;
  users.push("LOOP1-"+user.get("firstname"))
  console.log("LOOP1-User: "+user.get("firstname"))

  //promises2.push( // End Promise [1]
    return userQuery.each(function(user){ // userQuery.each [1]
      if (user == currentUser){
        console.log("$$$$$$$ SAME USER $$$$$$$")
      } else {
        if (currentUser.get("memberIDs").indexOf(user.get("memberId")) > -1 ){
          console.log("Found (different) member!")

        }
      }
      users.push("LOOP2-"+user.get("firstname"))
      console.log("LOOP2-User: "+user.get("firstname"))
    }) // End userQuery.each [0]
  //) // End Promise [1]
}) // End userQuery.each [0]
  ) // End Promise [0]
  Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
console.log(users)
status.success("Success")
  }, function(error){
status.error(error)
  })

}) // end Cloud.Job("doSth")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me qualify my answer with everything I know about Parse Cloud, I learned in the past 5 minutes looking at their API.

But, to answer the question, it looks like when you run a `Parse.Cloud.job`, the job returns a promise as well.  In your code where you run the job defined in the question, do you have success/error handlers on the job run output?

I won't suggest another comparison technique, since I have no idea what this code does in the scope of your app, but I would like to suggest that when you are nesting functions, refrain from using the same variable name multiple times. `user` has different contexts within your code, so it'd be easier to read if you use a different variable name for your inner function call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just edited my post with my solution with promises. I studied the docs for almost 5h to find this...

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to my own question**
Solved my problem using parallel promises!

```
Parse.Cloud.job("doSth", function(request, status) { // begin Cloud.Job("doSth")
  var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var users = []
  var promises = []
  promises.push( // Start Promise [0]
userQuery.each(function(user){ // userQuery.each [0]

  var currentUser = user;
  users.push("LOOP1-"+user.get("firstname"))
  console.log("LOOP1-User: "+user.get("firstname"))

  //promises2.push( // End Promise [1]
    return userQuery.each(function(user){ // userQuery.each [1]
      if (user == currentUser){
        console.log("$$$$$$$ SAME USER $$$$$$$")
      } else {
        if (currentUser.get("memberIDs").indexOf(user.get("memberId")) > -1 ){
          console.log("Found (different) member!")

        }
      }
      users.push("LOOP2-"+user.get("firstname"))
      console.log("LOOP2-User: "+user.get("firstname"))
    }) // End userQuery.each [0]
  //) // End Promise [1]
}) // End userQuery.each [0]
  ) // End Promise [0]
  Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
console.log(users)
status.success("Success")
  }, function(error){
status.error(error)
  })

}) // end Cloud.Job("doSth")
```